# installing asp.mvc 2 beta nunit project templates untrusted component error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, nunit, project-template

I've been trying to get nunit 2.5 to work with mvc 2 (VS2008) after following some [guides](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/11/17/nunit-templates-for-asp-net-mvc-2-0-preview-2/) and updating registries. I though I was done. I can select nunit when choosing my testing frame work but there is no test project created. When I create a new mvcapplication.nunit.tests template it fails with the error.

> Error: this template attempted to load an untrusted component 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions', Version 9.0.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I'm a little lost as to where to find the component and how to make it trusted.

Comment: Do you have all your service paks installed. This was an issue for VS 2005 as well and installing the SP resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer at this point is to change the problem...

Use Visual Studio 2010, the MVC3 platform and this plugin via nuget

https://nuget.org/packages/nunit